# Solving for all equations of x trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for all the values of $x$.

$$\tan^2 x=\tan x
$$

I don't know how to do this. I've tried similar examples but have failed to get this one.

Comment: Is that $\tan(x^2)$ or $\tan(x)^2$?

Comment: I just wrote it in this way, its actually tan then squared and x behind it. Its all one term written as trig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $ m = \tan x,$ then you have $$0 = m^2 - m = m(m-1)$$  solving this we get $$m = 0, m = 1. $$  the solutions are $$x = k\pi, \pi/4 + k \pi \text{ where } k \text{ any integer.}$$

Comment: is m equivalent to x? and are there only 2 solutions written as 3.14/4.

Comment: @user242559, i labelled $m$ as $\tan x.$ the only solutions between $0$ and $2\pi$ are $0, \pi/4, \pi, 5\pi/4, 2\pi.$ in degrees, it is $0^\circ, 45^\circ, 215^\circ, 360^\circ$